# finding string when enter position

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have an array `alpha={"A","B","C”}` and in console if I enter 0 it should display `A(position of A = 0)` in same way `1=B` and `2=C`. I have to achieve this in Java.
I have a similar code, but it returns different output. Can someone suggest me code to get output as in my question.

```
public class Position{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String Alpha = ("abcd");
        for (int i = 0 ; i<Alpha .length() ; i++)
        if (Alpha .charAt(i) == 'd')
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `Map` for this.

Comment: @Kon Seems not needed *IMHO*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String args[]){
   String[] alpha= {"A","B","C","D"};
   for (int i = 0 ; i < alpha.length ; i++){
      if(Integer.valueOf(args[0]) == i){
          System.out.println(alpha[i] + " is at position " +i);
      }
   }
}
```

You can enter the position in the arguments when you run your java program.

Answer (score 1):

> I have an array alpha={"A","B","C”} and in console if i enter 0 it should display A(position of A = 0)

```
 String[] alpha={"A","B","C"} ;
```

Then if you want to access element at `0` simply you could do

`alpha[0]` gives you `"A"`

```
String result = alpha[0];
```

Comment: In console I have to enter 0 and should print A and same for rest.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Position{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String[] alpha={"A","B","C”} ;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); //read reading from console
        String entered = br.readLine();
        int index = Integer.parseInt(entered);
        System.out.println(alpha[index]); // This will print out "A" if you enter 0
    }
```

}